# Fetch data from header in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to fetch token data from header in asp.net core, How can I do that?
in PHP I use `$_SERVER["HTTP_TOKEN"]` but in asp.net core I don't know how can I do that.
I'm beginner in ASP.net Core API.
I searched a lot in internet but I couldn't find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get header value in asp.net core try the code below

```
StringValues headerValue;  
Request.Headers.TryGetValue("HTTP_TOKEN", out headerValue);  
var headerValueResult= headerValue.FirstOrDefault();
```